# How SQLite reads data from disk?

Tags: sqlite

I just wondered and start reading SQLite source code.

There weren't any fopen,fclose except logging functions.
I tried to track down `sqlite3_open`, `sqlite3_prepare`, I came into `sqlite3parse` and stuck.

There is `fopen` in

```
sqlite3MemdebugDump
sqlite3Memsys3Dump
sqlite3Memsys5Dump
sqlite3VdbeTransferError
```

which are debug functions.

Are they wrote their own disk handler?

(I always stunned how professional applications handle this kind of things.)

Summary: How SQLite handle files without `fopen`?

Comment: It uses [mmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) on UNIX, and probably the equivalent on Windows.

Comment: What are the downvotes for? Certainly, this question has a definitive verifiable answer that can be provided by someone who knows the SQLite code sufficiently well and can explain why the OP did not find what they were looking for?!

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Agreed. Moreover, this is quite interesting. Unfortunately  people seem to downvote without thinking too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite accesses files through its [OS interface](http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html), which is implemented in the `os_*.c` files.

Comment: why it doesn't use fopen like most apps do?

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Comment: @user1156885 It depends on your usecase. The main reasons are performance and ease of use. With `mmap` you can e.g. just use array operations instead of having to use `fseek` every time.